# increasing size of text in plot in R (cex parameter doesn't work)

Tags: r, plot, tree

I am trying to plot a tree with R. with normal `cex` parameter the plot looks like image below. size of box are too big but text are readable. When I decrease the `cex` to `0.5` size of box are good but text are not readable (too small) (image at bottom). I wonder how can I plot the image below with the text size of upper image?

[image]

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Please share some code.

Comment: @r2evans, it is not possible to provide my data. but after training I use this code for plotting data,`ptree<- prune(model_tree,cp=0.003) 
fancyRpartPlot(ptree, uniform=TRUE,cex=0.5)`

Comment: The help page refers to `rpart.plot::prp` which includes a `tweak` parameter. Did you try that?